# Fill the width of div with button and input

Tags: html, css, button, input

I need to fill a div element with a button and input. The button'll have the exact width and fthe rest will be filled with the input. In my code I can't even set the width of the button and the input is always wider than the parent.

Then I'll set `overlay: hidden` to the `.bar` so that the input with the button look like I want. But for that to behave like I want, I need to set the mentioned widths correctly. So what could I do to fill this parent div with this button of exact width and input for the rest of its width but no more than that? I tried lots of properties, nothing helped. Only condition is, that I want `display: flex` remain in the code, everything else can be changed. Thanks for suggestions.

```css
.container {
  width:205px;
}

.bar {
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  //overflow: hidden;
}

.bar_input {
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}

.bar_button {
  padding: 8px 8px 14px 1px;
  width: 37px;
  height: 35px;
  left: 3px;
  right: auto;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container u-l-fr" style="background-color: darkred">
    <div class="container-bar" style="background-color: darkblue">
      <div class="bar" style="background-color: gold">
        <button aria-label="Search" class="bar_button" role="button" type="button" style="background-color: black;"></button>
        <input class="bar_input" id="search_input" placeholder="Search">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because your container width is less than the default width that is assigned to a `<input>` element. So you can either increase `width` of your container or use this code.

```
.bar_input {
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(100% - 37px);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this default width.

Comment: happy to help. keep coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Using bootstrap you can add class to the button .btn-block
Otherwise you can add style width: 100%; to the button

Comment: I don't want to start using bootstrap in my project just for this little thing. As I said, I want to set exact width for the button and setting it to 100% changes nothing in this code, you can try it.